# Oracle's RETURNING INTO :variable equivalent using SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, oracle, sql-returning

I have the following code that works on Oracle:

```
OracleCommand command = conn.CreateCommand(); // conn is my connection

string sql = "INSERT INTO table_name (ID, NAME, GENDER) VALUES (1, 'JOHN', 'M') RETURNING ID INTO :returnedId";

command.CommandText = sql;
command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("returnedId", OracleDbType.Decimal));
command.ExecuteNoQuery();
```

I need to port that to SQL Server. This is what I'm doing:

```
SqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand(); // conn is my connection

string sql = "INSERT INTO table_name (Id, Name, Gender) OUTPUT Inserted.Id As returnedId VALUES (1, "JOHN", "M")";

command.CommandText = sql;
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("returnedId", SqlDbType.Decimal));
command.ExecuteNoQuery();
```

That code gives me the following error:

> the parameterized query expects the parameter which was not supplied: @returnedId

What's the correct way to migrate the `RETURNING` and the `:returnedId` clauses from Oracle to SQL Server ?

I've tried `OUTPUT Inserted.Id As @returnedId` as well as changing the `SqlParameter` to `"@returnedId"` with no success.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**OUTPUT**](http://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms177564.aspx) is *SQL Server*'s equivalent to [**RETURNING INTO**](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/returninginto_clause.htm).

```
INSERT INTO table_name (ID, NAME, GENDER) 
OUTPUT INSERTED.ID 
VALUES (1, 'JOHN', 'M') ;
```

And *C#* :

```
Int32 outputID = (Int32)command.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: Can you please better elaborate ? I´ve added the table creation but still not working... Remember I´m using C# code to get the Id data.